# How to set a POST data in value in FAPI

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to port a working FAPI module from  D6 to D7.
I'm passing a POST value to the form and then assigning using :

```
 $link = check_url(substr($_POST['file_link'], 0, 300));
     $form['anu_download_file_link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $link,
      );
```

But when form is submitted the form is built again but this POST data file_link is missing in the submit handler.

In D6 $form['#cache']=true was working fine which avoided recreating of the form but now in D7 it does not seem to work.

How can pass POST values to the submit handler?

Comment: how are you sending the post data?

Comment: what does this action link do "downloadsbrt/90n-brt-download-file-now" is it calling a url inside drupal?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using $form_state rather than POST if you're using the FAPI?

Comment: I dont see the form element with the name file link in there.

Comment: David Meister is right: if you are using `POST` you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you mean using $form_state['input'] ... rather than accessing $_POST directly? How'd that matter? In my case a  webpage is invoking a form-api using POST method from external site.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use in D7 :

```
$form_state['cache'] = TRUE;
$form_state['no_cache'] = FALSE;
```

instead of

```
$form['$cache']=TRUE in D6
```